# Very slow window changes in KDE

Tags: kde

I couldn't find any other reference to this sort of issue, so I'm hoping someone here might be able to help me.

For a while now, I've been noticing slow downs when I change a which window is on top. Currently I'm doing a lot of web dev stuff, so when I tab out of my IDE to a browser, the mouse will not register that the refresh icon is a button, and an F5 will actually execute on my IDE. I have to wait a second or two in order for the browser to now register as the top page.

This is incredibly annoying, and it happens across all windows. I'll move back to my IDE and try to scroll down it, only to have another window appear. I'll press keys and have them execute in the window not on top.

Hopefully someone's seen this, as I have no idea what to do. My focus settings are on the default (that being, whichever window is on top has focus), but besides that, I don't know of any other settings that relate.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Inxi stats

```
System:    Host: user-VMware Kernel: 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 8.2.0 
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.13.5 tk: Qt 5.11.1 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM 
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)

Machine:   Type: Vmware System: VMware product: VMware Virtual Platform v: N/A serial: <filter> 
           Chassis: No Enclosure type: 1 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Intel model: 440BX Desktop Reference Platform serial: <filter> BIOS: Phoenix v: 6.00 
           date: 04/13/2018

CPU:       Topology: 4x Single Core model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: SMP arch: Kaby Lake rev: 9 
           L2 cache: 24.0 MiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 bogomips: 22464 
           Speed: 2808 MHz min/max: N/A Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2808 2: 2808 3: 2808 4: 2808

Graphics:  Device-1: VMware SVGA II Adapter driver: vmwgfx v: 2.14.1.0 bus ID: 00:0f.0 chip ID: 15ad:0405 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: vmware unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
           compositor: kwin_x11 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: SVGA3D; build v: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2 compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes

Audio:     Device-1: Ensoniq ES1371/ES1373 / Creative Labs CT2518 driver: snd_ens1371 v: kernel bus ID: 02:04.0 
           chip ID: 1274:1371 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.18.0-15-generic

Network:   Device-1: Intel 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI type: network bridge driver: N/A port: N/A bus ID: 00:07.3 
           chip ID: 8086:7113 
           Device-2: Intel 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet driver: e1000 v: 7.3.21-k8-NAPI port: 2000 bus ID: 02:01.0 
           chip ID: 8086:100f 
           IF: ens33 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>

Drives:    Local Storage: total: 25.00 GiB used: 17.35 GiB (69.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: VMware model: Virtual SATA Hard Drive size: 25.00 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
           serial: <filter>

Partition: ID-1: / size: 24.54 GiB used: 17.35 GiB (70.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1

Sensors:   Message: No sensors data was found. Is sensors configured?

Info:      Processes: 277 Uptime: 16h 05m Memory: 11.73 GiB used: 7.09 GiB (60.4%) Init: systemd v: 239 
           runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 8.2.0 alt: 8 Shell: zsh v: 5.5.1 running in: konsole inxi: 3.0.24
```

Comment: Please install *inxi* and then post the output of *inxi -Fxxz* so that people get an idea of your system specs.

Comment: @DKBose Updated with Inxi output. The system is being ran through VMware, but I don't have this issue in any other OS. As I realize it doesn't say it, the drive is sat on an NVME SSD, so it shouldn't be any sort of load issue.